# Package 'certbot' is not installed, so not removed

Tags: nginx, apache2, digital-ocean, ubuntu-20.04, certbot

I am using ubuntu 20.04 server in digital ocean. I have installl certbot. When i see the version name it shows certbot 1.22.0. But when i have tried to uninstall certbot. I got that message that Package certbot is not installed, so not removed. Can you please help me why it is happening. I am using apache as a web server and nginx as a proxy server.
Than you advance.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your using **apt**, use apt search certbot and try **apt remove** on every certbot package from the list.

If its not **certbot** then its probably **certbot-auto** or **letsencrypt**